# django: unexpected file download after redirect when file does not exist

Tags: python, django, download, response, response.redirect

Django==1.11.12

If the file exists, the view function creates `StreamingHttpResponse` and all is fine. But if the file does not exist, the view function should redirect. The problem is, it does not redirect but instead prompt up to ask to save as a file, which has the content of redirected html.

```py
import os
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
import mimetypes
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def download(request, file_path):
    try:
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
            FileWrapper(open(file_path, 'rb'), chunk_size),
            content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)[0])
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=a_file.xlsx")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        response = redirect("home")
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem lays in template, where the download link is `<a href="xxx" download>` and the download attribute force the download.